# Registring the regions

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container, region

Using Prism, I've got a INFRASTRUCTURE project, where I've got a view with two regions:

- ContentRegion
- SidebarRegion

[image]

There's no problem in `SidebarRegion`, because this is a especif view of this project. But `ContentRegion` is different, I've got another modules like `ModuleA`, `ModuleB`, and these one contain the view which must be show in `ContentRegion`.

I mean, the INFRASTRUCTURE PROJECT contains the generic view. And the others module contains a view which must be showed in `ContentRegion`

I'm using Prism and UNITY. Can you orient me about how can I do this? I guess I need to register the views but I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the Region Manager and Unity container to the modules through the constructor.  Then you can use those to register your views in the `Initialize` method, like so:

```
public class ModuleA : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ModuleA(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion",
            () => _container.Resolve<NameOfYourView>());
    }
}
```

And, of course, you have to make sure the modules are loaded properly, but I'm assuming that is done already.

Comment: aren't there any problem if I use several modules? I mean, an error because the regions has already registered.

Comment: Do the views in `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` define other regions?  And are they using the same names that you used in your infrastructure project?

Comment: No, they aren't defining other regions. When the module initializes, I just put that code you set.. and I'm receiving that error. 

Maybe I need to comment also that each Module is showing in a TabControl